# Linq To Sql - SQL Default Constraint Problem

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, constraints

I have a USER table in database. The table has a RegistrationDate column which has a default constraint as GETDATE().

When using LINQ, I don't provide any data for RegistrationDate column to make it default. But SQL Server raises error. I think LINQ tries to insert NULL into the column.

How can I make LINQ not to try to insert in the column RegistrationDate, because it has default value?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set `Auto Generated Value` property to `true` in the designer.

Or `IsDbGenerated="true"` in `.dbml` file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but you could make the property read-only in the DBML designer.