# Default database field value of GETDATE() still returns SqlDateTime overflow

Tags: c#, datetime, linq-to-sql, getdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linq To Sql - SQL Default Constraint Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743797/linq-to-sql-sql-default-constraint-problem)

My database table as a column called `date_created` defined as follows:

```
date_created DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

I'm using Linq-to-SQL classes. I create a new object, populate it (omitting a value for `date_created` as that's supposed to sort itself out) and as soon as I call `SubmitChanges` it returns an error:

> *SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM*

Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: Did you define that property in your Linq-to-SQL model as "database generated"? Otherwise, Linq-to-SQL will still try to set the value.... easiest solution: just set the value `date_created = DateTime.Now;` in your code...

Comment: Well maybe since you omitted the value of the DateTime variable was set to `DateTime.MinValue`  which would be causing it to throw the error